# Why isn't Midje reporting successes when run from CLI?

Tags: clojure

I'm [experimenting with Clojure 1.9's tools.deps](https://github.com/ethagnawl/tools-deps-experiment) and came up with a contrived example which uses Midje to run tests. I followed [this](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Using-midje-without-Leiningen) guide when getting started, but since I'm using the assumed directory structure, the stated configs don't seem to be necessary.

Unfortunately, I'm seeing unexpected behavior in Midje's output when running the tests: successes are not reported as expected (e.g. `All checks (1) succeeded.`). Interestingly, failures are reported as expected.

I've tried bumping the print-level, which is picked up as the namespace and facts are reported correctly, but that still doesn't result in the final summary being printed.

Here are the relevant files:

test/hello/test.clj:

```
(ns hello.test
  (:use midje.sweet))

(defn -main []
  (facts "facts"
    (fact "fact"
      1 => 1)))
```

deps.edn:

```
{:deps
 {clj-time {:mvn/version "0.14.2"}
  midje {:mvn/version "1.9.2-alpha3"}}

 :aliases
 {:test {:extra-paths ["test"]}}}
```

The tests are being run via: `clj -A:test -m hello.test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call something like `(midje.repl/check-facts :all)`.
See [this wiki page](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Repl-tools) for more information.

Comment: That was spot-on. I created a `test-runner` namespace, which uses `midje.repl` to call `(load-facts)`, and calling into that namespace from the CLI results in everything working as expected. Thanks!